# Solution to $\left\{\begin{matrix}ax-aby+\frac{1}{xy}=bc^2 & & \\ abz-bc^2x+\frac{1}{xz}=a& & \\ bc^2y-az+\frac{1}{yz}=ab& & \end{matrix}\right.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\left\{\begin{matrix}ax-aby+\frac{1}{xy}=bc^2 &  & \\  abz-bc^2x+\frac{1}{xz}=a&  & \\  bc^2y-az+\frac{1}{yz}=ab&  & \end{matrix}\right.$

Answer (score 4):

You can usually avoid a lot of calculation when finding solutions to an equation exploiting the fact that when looking for vanishing points of a fraction the denominator becomes irrelevant (after marking all the points where it vanishes as excluded from the domain of definition.

Specifically in your case, you may rewrite the last equation your mentioned as $\frac{ac + bc - 2ab}{ab} = 0$ and look for vanishing points of $ac+bc-2ab$.

Note that $ac+bc-2ab=c(a+b)-2ab=\frac{c(a^2-b^2)}{a-b}-2ab=\frac{c(a^2-b^2)-2(a^2b+b^2a)}{a-b}$, so in order for the original equation to vanish we need that $c(b^2-a^2)-2(a^2b+b^2a)=0$.

The same calculation, replacing the roles of $a$ and $b$, shows that it is also required that $c(a^2-b^2)-2(a^2b+b^2a)=0$ and combining them both yields that $c(a^2-b^2)=c(b^2-a^2)$.

That is, that $c(-2x+2)=c(2x-2)$ which is only possible if either $x=1$ or $c=0$. But an instant calculation shows that $c=0$ iff $x=1$ so the only possible solution is $x=1$, and a direct substitution shows that it is indeed a solution.

Comment: In line about $ac+bc-2ab=c(a+b)-2ab=\frac{c(a^2-b^2)}{a-b}-2ab=\frac{c(a^2-b^2)-2(a^2b+b^2a)}{a-b}$. You was wrong in $\frac{c(a^2-b^2)}{a-b}-2ab=\frac{c(a^2-b^2)-2(a^2b+b^2a)}{a-b}$